# How to distinguish input files in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I'm just trying to understand how Hadoop distinguish multiple files in HDFS. I want to do sentiment analysis using Hadoop (just a test). I have two files `positive.json` and `negative.json`. I'm trying to use Naive Bayes Classification. So, when I train the model, I want to know which ones are positive and which ones are negative. How do I do this? I haven't written any codes to show; I'm stuck in the first part. Any suggestions? I did read tons of papers, and I think I do have a basic concept. I want to see if I can use this concept in Rhipe. Or do you have any other better and easier solutions?

Comment: Which tool you want to use? Mahout or Spark?

Comment: @zsxwing Do I have to use one of those? I was thinking just Rhipe. Can it not be done on Rhipe, or is it better to use Mahout or Spark?

Comment: @zsxwing Sorry, I misread your question. Whichever is better or easier.

Comment: @zsxwing I installed Mahout (0.7) on CDH4 (hadoop 2.0.0). The installation completed successfully, but I get these error messages when I run `bin/classify-20newsgroups.sh`  `/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/bin/hdfs: line 24: /usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/bin/../libexec/hdfs-config.sh: No such file or directory /usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/bin/hdfs: line 140: cygpath: command not found /usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/bin/hdfs: line 172: exec: : not found + set -e.` I couldn't find out what it means. Any idea?